Navigating While Mapping - Ackermann vehicle
I've been trying to do this https://navigation.ros.org/tutorials/docs/navigation2_with_slam.html but with a ackermann vehicle.
The localization and the mapping seem off.
Here is a video that shows what I mean. (the video is at x3 speed)
I'm quite new to Nav2, I would like to know what I did wrongly. Did I perhaps set my nav2 params wrongly and I should tune them better? Or is something else the cause?
Thank you
EDIT
Here is my params file:
bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    odom_topic: /odom
    default_bt_xml_filename: "navigate_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml"
    bt_loop_duration: 10
    default_server_timeout: 20
    enable_groot_monitoring: True
    groot_zmq_publisher_port: 1666
    groot_zmq_server_port: 1667
    plugin_lib_names:
    - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
    - nav2_compute_path_through_poses_action_bt_node
    - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
    - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
    - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
    - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
    - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
    - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
    - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_truncate_path_action_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_updater_node_bt_node
    - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
    - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
    - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
    - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_single_trigger_bt_node
    - nav2_is_battery_low_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_navigate_through_poses_action_bt_node
    - nav2_navigate_to_pose_action_bt_node
    - nav2_remove_passed_goals_action_bt_node
    - nav2_planner_selector_bt_node
    - nav2_controller_selector_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_checker_selector_bt_node

bt_navigator_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    controller_frequency: 20.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.3
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.01
    progress_checker_plugins: ["progress_checker"]
    goal_checker_plugins: ["goal_checker"]
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]

    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 10.0
    goal_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.15
      stateful: True
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "nav2_regulated_pure_pursuit_controller::RegulatedPurePursuitController"
      desired_linear_vel: 0.3
      lookahead_dist: 0.9
      min_lookahead_dist: 0.3
      max_lookahead_dist: 1.5
      lookahead_time: 1.5
      rotate_to_heading_angular_vel: 1.0
      transform_tolerance: 0.1
      use_velocity_scaled_lookahead_dist: false
      min_approach_linear_velocity: 0.05
      approach_velocity_scaling_dist: 1.0
      use_collision_detection: false
      max_allowed_time_to_collision_up_to_carrot: 1.0
      use_regulated_linear_velocity_scaling: true
      use_cost_regulated_linear_velocity_scaling: false
      regulated_linear_scaling_min_radius: 0.9
      regulated_linear_scaling_min_speed: 0.25
      use_fixed_curvature_lookahead: true
      curvature_lookahead_dist: 1.0
      use_rotate_to_heading: false

      allow_reversing: true
      
      rotate_to_heading_min_angle: 0.0
      max_angular_accel: 3.2
      max_robot_pose_search_dist: 10.0
      interpolate_curvature_after_goal: false
      cost_scaling_dist: 0.3
      cost_scaling_gain: 1.0
      inflation_cost_scaling_factor: 3.0


controller_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 5.0
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: odom
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: False
      rolling_window: true
      width: 10
      height: 10
      resolution: 0.05
      footprint: "[ [0.28, 0.65], [0.28, -0.65], [-1.93, -0.65], [-1.93, 0.65] ]"
      plugins: ["obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        inflation_radius: 0.7
        cost_scaling_factor: 8.0
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
      static_layer:
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  local_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
  local_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False

global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: True
      footprint: "[ [0.28, 0.65], [0.28, -0.65], [-1.93, -0.65], [-1.93, 0.65] ]"
      resolution: 0.05
      track_unknown_space: true
      plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 4.0
        inflation_radius: 0.4
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  global_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
  global_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False

map_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    yaml_filename: /home/lobna/ros2_ws/map_serial

map_saver:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    save_map_timeout: 5.0
    free_thresh_default: 0.25
    occupied_thresh_default: 0.65
    map_subscribe_transient_local: True

planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    use_sim_time: True

    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_smac_planner/SmacPlannerHybrid"
      tolerance: 0.5                                    # tolerance for planning if unable to reach exact pose, in meters
      downsample_costmap: false                         # whether or not to downsample the map
      downsampling_factor: 1                            # multiplier for the resolution of the costmap layer (e.g. 2 on a 5cm costmap would be 10cm)
      allow_unknown: true                               # allow traveling in unknown space
      max_iterations: 1000000                           # maximum total iterations to search for before failing (in case unreachable), set to -1 to disable
      max_on_approach_iterations: 1000                  # maximum number of iterations to attempt to reach goal once in tolerance
      max_planning_time: 5.0                            # max time in s for planner to plan, smooth, and upsample. Will scale maximum smoothing and upsampling times based on remaining time after planning.
      motion_model_for_search: "REEDS_SHEPP"            # For Hybrid Dubin (DUBIN), Redds-Shepp (REEDS_SHEPP)
      cost_travel_multiplier: 2.0                       # For 2D: Cost multiplier to apply to search to steer away from high cost areas. Larger values will place in the center of aisles more exactly (if non-`FREE` cost potential field exists) but take slightly longer to compute. To optimize for speed, a value of 1.0 is reasonable. A reasonable tradeoff value is 2.0. A value of 0.0 effective disables steering away from obstacles and acts like a naive binary search A*.
      angle_quantization_bins: 64                       # For Hybrid nodes: Number of angle bins for search, must be 1 for 2D node (no angle search)
      analytic_expansion_ratio: 3.5                     # For Hybrid/Lattice nodes: The ratio to attempt analytic expansions during search for final approach.
      analytic_expansion_max_length: 3.0                # For Hybrid/Lattice nodes: The maximum length of the analytic expansion to be considered valid to prevent unsafe shortcutting (in meters). This should be scaled with minimum turning radius and be no less than 4-5x the minimum radius
      minimum_turning_radius: 1.663                     # For Hybrid/Lattice nodes: minimum turning radius in m of path / vehicle
      reverse_penalty: 4.1                              # For Reeds-Shepp model: penalty to apply if motion is reversing, must be => 1
      change_penalty: 1.0                               # For Hybrid nodes: penalty to apply if motion is changing directions, must be >= 0
      non_straight_penalty: 2.20                        # For Hybrid nodes: penalty to apply if motion is non-straight, must be => 1
      cost_penalty: 2.0                                 # For Hybrid nodes: penalty to apply to higher cost areas when adding into the obstacle map dynamic programming distance expansion heuristic. This drives the robot more towards the center of passages. A value between 1.3 - 3.5 is reasonable.
      retrospective_penalty: 0.025                      # For Hybrid/Lattice nodes: penalty to prefer later maneuvers before earlier along the path. Saves search time since earlier nodes are not expanded until it is necessary. Must be >= 0.0 and <= 1.0
      rotation_penalty: 20.0                            # For Lattice node: Penalty to apply only to pure rotate in place commands when using minimum 
                                                        # control sets containing rotate in place primitives. This should always be set sufficiently high
                                                        # to weight against this action unless strictly necessary for obstacle avoidance or there may be 
                                                        # frequent discontinuities in the plan where it requests the robot to rotate in place to short-cut 
                                                        # an otherwise smooth path for marginal path distance savings.
      lookup_table_size: 20.0                           # For Hybrid nodes: Size of the dubin/reeds-sheep distance window to cache, in meters.
      cache_obstacle_heuristic: True                    # For Hybrid nodes: Cache the obstacle map dynamic programming distance expansion heuristic between subsiquent replannings of the same goal location. Dramatically speeds up replanning performance (40x) if costmap is largely static.  
      allow_reverse_expansion: False                    # For Lattice nodes: Whether to expand state lattice graph in forward primitives or reverse as well, will double the branching factor at each step.   
      smooth_path: True                                 # For Lattice/Hybrid nodes: Whether or not to smooth the path, always true for 2D nodes.
      smoother:
        max_iterations: 1000
        w_smooth: 0.3
        w_data: 0.2
        tolerance: 1.0e-10
        do_refinement: true                             # Whether to recursively run the smoother 3 times on the results from prior runs to refine the results further

planner_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

recoveries_server:
  ros__parameters:
    costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 10.0
    recovery_plugins: ["spin", "backup", "wait"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Spin"
    backup:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/BackUp"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Wait"
    global_frame: odom
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    transform_timeout: 0.1
    use_sim_time: true
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 1.0
    min_rotational_vel: 0.4
    rotational_acc_lim: 3.2

robot_state_publisher:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

waypoint_follower:
  ros__parameters:
    loop_rate: 200
    stop_on_failure: false
    waypoint_task_executor_plugin: "wait_at_waypoint"
    wait_at_waypoint:
      plugin: "nav2_waypoint_follower::WaitAtWaypoint"
      enabled: True
      waypoint_pause_duration: 200


Your problem seems to be within the navigation behavior right? For that issue you should use an Ackerman specific global planner such as SMAC variations. I use the SMAC planner for my robot take a look into the configuration file below
#GLOBAL PLANNER
planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    expected_planner_frequency: 20.0  # Expected frequency for the planner to run in Hz.
    planner_patience: 30.0  # Maximum time in seconds the planner waits for a valid plan
 
 
    #use_sim_time: True  # If simulation time should be used.
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_smac_planner/SmacPlannerHybrid"  # The plugin used for planning, here Hybrid-A*.
      downsample_costmap: false  #switched to true to see if reach greater paths # Whether the costmap should be downsampled.
      transform_tolerance: 1.0 #0.3 # Increased over 3 times the time tolerance to calculate a path, otherwise just close waypoints will produce a path, since it take time to generate a path for large areas
      downsampling_factor: 1
      allow_unknown: true  # If planning through unknown space is allowed.
      tolerance: 2.0  # Tolerance for planning in meters: Given the size of truck 1 meter is not so huge...
      max_iterations: 1000000 #1000000  # Max iterations the planner can take before stopping.
      max_on_approach_iterations: 1000  # Iterations to try to find an exact solution once within goal tolerance.
      max_planning_time: 30.0 #30.0 #15.0  # Max planning time in seconds.# I have doubled the time to allow computate far waypoitns, wich require more time to produce a bigger path (greater lenght)
      motion_model_for_search: "DUBIN"  # The motion model used for planning. "DUBIN" for non-holonomic robots without reverse gear, "REEDS_SHEPP" for those with.
      angle_quantization_bins: 72 #36 # Number of bins for quantizing angles. More bins, the finer the search . Reduced to provide more straight paths instead the curvy ones being produced which is not compatible for aligned waypoints of GPS.
      minimum_turning_radius: 11.6 # Minimum turning radius for the vehicle in meters. 11.6 official value given by manual
      reverse_penalty: 2.0  # Penalty for reversing. Higher values discourage reversing.
      change_penalty: 2.0  # Penalty for changing direction.
      non_straight_penalty: 3.0 #1.5 #1.2  # Penalty for non-straight motions. Encourages straighter paths.
      cost_penalty: 3.0 #3.0  # Penalty for traversing high-cost cells. Higher values make the robot more cost-sensitive.
      retrospective_penalty: 0.03
      lookup_table_size: 25.0 # Increased for complex environment handling
      cache_obstacle_heuristic: True  # Caches the heuristic calculations for obstacle-laden areas to speed up planning.
      debug_visualizations: True  # Enables debug visualizations in RViz.
      analytic_expansion_ratio: 20.0  # Multiplier for how often analytic expansions are attempted.
      analytic_expansion_max_length: 100.0 #3.0  # Maximum allowed length for an analytic expansion.
      analytic_expansion_max_cost: 800 #200.0  # The maximum single cost for any part of an analytic expansion to contain and be valid, except when necessary on approach to goal
      analytic_expansion_max_cost_override: True #false # Whether or not to override the maximum cost setting if within critical distance to goal (ie probably required)
      smooth_path: True
      allow_primitive_interpolation: True #This adds additional motion primitives that can help create more direct paths between points.
# Each of these parameters allows for fine-tuning the planner's behavior to suit the specific needs of your application and the characteristics of the environment.
# The analytic_expansion_ratio and analytic_expansion_max_length, for example, are particularly useful in complex or highly constrained environments where the standard grid-based search might struggle to find an optimal path.

You can share your configuration file next time with pastebin it will be easier to debug.
Localization won't work while you are mapping, just later when you use the map. The mapping functionality seems to be working normally. Instead using the planner to map you could run Teleop command to map the room manually. For Ackerman robots you use "bcr Teleop package", you need to download this pkg since is external from nav2.

Hi, thank you. I have added my params file in the question.
If I use a small sized vehicle the  localization works during the mapping (also this is shown in the nav2 tutorial). But if I use a bigger vehicle it doesn't work.
And if localisation is not possible while mapping is there any way to make the vehicle go to a goal position without having a prior map of the environment?

oh I am not using amcl localization since, I switched to GPS usage. However it indeed works with bigger vehicles. I remember last year I used with my Truck on simulation ( 10 meters length). I think maybe you need to change some param or inspect the files amcl use and change them. Maybe the map resolution? Not sure what is the specific error the terminal outputs you regarding amcl? The particles are not appearing in your map?
